# unable to import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android

And these two import are showing greyed out.
`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

==========================================================================
My dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'    '
```

===========================================================================
I am not getting autosuggest of the dependencies which I have implemented, which we usually get when we implement. Please Help. It's been a week I am stuck. PleaseHelp.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_home" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    app:scrCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"/>
```

Comment: Try rebuilding the project

Comment: I tried it is not working

Comment: the last line "<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    app:scrCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"/>" is showing error. says resources not found

Answer (score 1):

You're using AndroidX classes while using legacy support dependencies.

Use their equivalent AndroidX versions:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
```

Comment: I tried but still the Cart Icoin is not showing. and also my the two import 1) android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity. 2)android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar are showing greyout.

Comment: Try "Migrate to AndroidX" via refactor menu

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the activity and recreate the activity, which resolved my issue. And thanks for Androidx dependencies which also helps me out. THank you!!!